# Need a jQuery Carousel

Tags: jquery, carousel

I am after a fairly specific type of jQuery Carousel.

I want to be able to display a dynamic list of images in a 3D carousel, where the thumbnails "float" around in the space.

I have found a carousel, but the images are in a plain circular shape. I need the images to be staggered about and pop to the front when clicked.

To add to this, I need it to work alongside facebox (or any other lightbox plugin)

p.s. here is the carousel I have atm, it just about works, but is glitchy and the setup is terrible http://fredhq.com/projects/roundabout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know that the statement from Elad is exactly true. HTML5 certainly is making a case that flash/silverlight could be obsolete in a couple years. In the meanby, there are examples of non-HTML5 solutions: [jquery-ui example](http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/branches/labs/carousel/demo/slider.html), [professorcloud example](http://www.professorcloud.com/mainsite/carousel.htm).

Nifty plug-in Luke, gonna put that in my pocket for use at some other point. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think images floating in 3D space is a task for flash. Even if this could be done in javascript, I think it would be very bulky. JS is not big on image transformations.

Comment: I think the issue there is that I need it to work with this dynamically created list. Most Flash solutions I have seen use XML files to feed the animation with data, but this is not an option sadly. I have spotted a few 3D galleries, but they don't seem to be very feature rich.

Answer (score 0):

What about [IMAGEFLOW?](http://imageflow.finnrudolph.de/)

Comment: Sort of. I need it to be auto-playing and the images to be staggered about, not in a straight line (e.g. on imageflow, bottom of all images are like _ _ _ _ _ i'd like _ _ - _ - - )